# Error while unserializing user data in symfony authentication

Tags: security, symfony, serialization, offset

my first question here. I have been sitting on it for few hours and couldn't find solution:
The error pops out when the user is successfuly found in DB and i guess symfony tries to serialize it's data into session.

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 37 of 49 bytes in G:\cebuland\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken.php line 163
```

Causes login process faliure.

User's Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="user")
     * @var $role Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $role;
...
    public function getRoles() {
        return $this->role->toArray();
    }
...
    public function serialize() {
        serialize(array(
            $this->id, 
            $this->name,
            $this->password,
            $this->created,
            $this->last_activity,
            $this->ghost,
            $this->role
        ));
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list(
            $this->id, 
            $this->name,
            $this->password,
            $this->created,
            $this->last_activity,
            $this->ghost,
            $this->role
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
```

Role's Entity is quite similiar.

And the security.yml configuration file:

```
security:
    providers:
        users:
            entity: {class: ApplicationMainBundle:User, property: name}
    encoders: 
        Application\MainBundle\Entity\User:
            #plain just for testing
            algorithm: plaintext 
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            logout: 
                path: /logout
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR}
```

Couldn't find a clue anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your User::serialize method does not return serialized string, but it should [Serializable::serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php)

Comment: @MarekLewandowski what did you do here to make it work? Can you post some code?

Comment: He is add return to function serialize()